# How to emulate sound physics in a 3d game?

Tags: audio, physics

What sort of algorithms do I use for simulating sound? Like, if the player approaches the source of a sound, it should get louder, but if the player goes farther away, it should get softer. That's the big thing I can't seem to figure out.

I don't require any code, mostly I just want the equations, assuming there is one.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-square_law#Acoustics

Answer (score 1):

What you are talking about is important just like the [Doppler effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppler_effect). In general, you need more than just calculate the distance of an object to the source of the sound upon location change. It is much better to take into account the following:

- the movement of the sound source
- the movement of the active object
- potential obstacles (for instance a wall)
- "approaching" and "departing" as special cases of the Doppler effect
- distance deviation in short time period

It should not be a goal to make this perfectly accurate, because in that case you would have to calculate too many things. Your aim should be to make this "good-enough" and the definition of "good-enough" should be made by you upon tests. Naturally, you need a lot of [formulas](http://www.sengpielaudio.com/calculator-soundpower.htm).